# Adding .war to solr 4 webapps

Tags: web-applications, migrate, solr4

I am new to Solr.
We were using solr 3 earlier and added a customer service.war file in solr webapps directory. Plus added a custom.jar file inside solr.war. And it is working fine.

Now for solr 4: I have added all the new fields to schema.xml file, updated the solr.war file with custom .jar and have put the service.war file in webapps directory..... rest  is untouched. I am able to run the solr service with no exception or error shown.

But when my web application invokes solr which should run my service.war file placed in webapps.... it gives error  :

Response - POST http..localhost..8983/myapp/service returned a response status of 404 Not Found

Please help...

Comment: need clarification, are you migrating from Solr 3 to Classic Solr 4 or SolrCloud? also can you post details about exception or errors you're getting.

Comment: I got what I was expecting.... check answer below. Thanks for the reply....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done: I figured it out. 
In Solr 4, we need to create .xml file in context folder for each webapps.war added ....

For example: 
In context folder there is a file solr.xml : copy that file and name it to same as your new webapps.war file you already added into webapps folder

Edit the new .xml file ;
change context path to : /your webapps name
change .war file name to your .war file
and if you want tomcat to extract it to some folder specitiy that. For e.g. solr extract it in solr-webapps. hyou can extract it in yourwebapp-webapps.

Remember if you use same extract location then one of the .war file service won't start.

I hope I am clear....